# Cardinality of $(A\times B)\cup(B\times A)$

Tags: discrete-mathematics, elementary-set-theory

Let $A$ and $B$ be finite sets and let $a=|A|$, $b=|B|$ and $c=|A\cap B|$.

Write an expression in terms of $a$, $b$ and $c$ that is equal to $|(A\times B)\cup(B\times A)|$ for every choice of $A$ and $B$.

If possible I would like to have some guidelines.

Comment: Your posting has already received $2$ votes to be closed, and is likely to be closed without an answer, unless you edit your posting.  See [this article](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/33190/how-to-avoid-downvotes-for-beginners-questions/33236#33236) 
 for a description of the information that you need to add to your posting in order to influence mathSE reviewers to react positively, rather than negatively, to your posting.  Please do not respond with comment(s).  The missing information belongs directly in the posting itself.

Comment: Welcome to MSE ! Take a [tour](https://math.stackexchange.com/tour). You'll find that simple "Here's the statement of my question, solve it for me" posts will be poorly received. What is better is for you to add context (with an [edit](https://math.stackexchange.com/posts/4419774/edit)): What you understand about the problem, what you've tried so far, etc.; something both to show you are part of the learning experience and to help us guide you to the appropriate help. You can consult [this link](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9959) for further guidance.

Comment: The people here are very sensitive about doing people's homework for them, so you had better write what you've got so far.

Comment: Since you don't understand the question, let's explain a bit: you have to compute the cardinality of the set $(A\times B)\cup(B\times A)$. Try it for small sets $A$ and $B$. If $A$ and $B$ are disjoint, the formula should be simple. If they are not ($c>0$), then you have to find out how many elements of $A\times B$ and $B\times A$ are common.

Comment: You should draw a picture. Draw A and B 1-dimensional as lines which overlap. Draw them twice on two axis. In between them you have a square in which you can mark the set of which you like to find the cardinality. Try to express it as a disjoint union of other sets.

Comment: @M.Reeves What do you mean by here ?

Comment: $\boxed{2ab - c(a+b-c)}$ is the answer . . . . Use it to check your work.

Comment: @M.Reeves Noted

Answer (score 2):

When you solve questions which involve two or three sets, a good way to get started is to draw a picture.

Draw $A$ and $B$ one dimensional as lines which overlap each other (the overlap is of course $A\cap B$). Draw them twice on two axis, one horizontally and one vertical. In between the two axis you have a square which represents $(A\cup B)\times (A\cup B)$. Now mark your set in it (the one of which you like to compute the cardinality) and try to express it as a disjoint union of easier subsets.

I hope it helps. Write a comment if you do not understand my description of the picture.